# Running contrast after a contrast in emmeans

Tags: r, lsmeans

I've been using emmeans for quite some time, read all the vignettes, and still can't wrap my head around it at times. Let's say I have the following:

```
> means <- emmeans(model, ~  a | b | c)
> 
> means
b = 0, c = 0:
                a  emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
                0 -1.2366 0.905 1192    -3.01    0.539
                1  4.2566 1.160 1192     1.98    6.532

b = 1, c = 0:
                a  emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
                0  3.7970 1.122 1192     1.60    5.998
                1  0.3878 1.313 1192    -2.19    2.963

b = 0, c = 1:
                a  emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
                0 -0.2649 0.910 1192    -2.05    1.521
                1  9.4603 1.395 1192     6.72   12.197

b = 1, c = 1:
                a  emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
                0 -0.0577 1.035 1192    -2.09    1.972
                1  9.1992 1.561 1192     6.14   12.261
```

First, I want to run a `revpairwise` contrast within each group like so:

```
contr <- contrast(means, method = "revpairwise", adjust = "none")

> contr
b = 0, c = 0:
 contrast estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
 1 - 0        5.49 1.47 1192   3.734  0.0002

b = 1, c = 0:
 contrast estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
 1 - 0       -3.41 1.73 1192  -1.974  0.0486

b = 0, c = 1:
 contrast estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
 1 - 0        9.73 1.67 1192   5.839  <.0001

b = 1, c = 1:
 contrast estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
 1 - 0        9.26 1.87 1192   4.944  <.0001
```

Now I want to run an additional contrast in which I subtract the first row from the second row, and the third row from the fourth row.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
contr_final <- contrast(contr, 
         list("Contrast 1" = c(1,-1,0,0), 
              "Contrast 2" = c(0,0,1,-1),
         by = NULL,
         adjust = "none"))
```

But I get the error `Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :  arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 0, 1`

I've been debugging for an hour now, so would really appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Parentheses error. Put a closing paren before `, by` and remove the last closing paren. This is really a SO question.

Comment: Good lord... I truly need to get some sleep. Thank you. BTW, is this how you would go about running these contrasts? This three step procedure seems a bit inefficient, so I'm wondering if it's the best way to do it.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I have made a similar error. Actually, I do think this might be the best approach, as it is a non-standard interaction contrast. For standard ones (i.e. named contrast families), interaction contrasts can be generated in one step via `contrast(..., interaction = ...)`. But this can be confusing, and for me, methodical, small steps are easier to think about.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks again for your patience. Take care!